# pyQt5 Qslider with labels

Tags: python, pyqt5, qslider

I have created a Qt form with a QSlider in it as shown below.

```py
    self.np_label = QLabel("Number of Processors")
    self.np_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.np_slider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    self.np_slider.setMinimum(0)
    self.np_slider.setMaximum(10)
    self.np_slider.setTickInterval(2)
    self.np_slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
```

But I'm not able to set the tick labels. Are there any direct method to do so?

[image]